# How to push a new UIViewController from react-native to Objective-C Native bridge

Tags: objective-c, react-native, uiviewcontroller, react-native-ios

Can I push a new UIViewController from react-native to Objective-C Native bridge? I want to run the native screen from react-native. I don't want to implement native UI to a react-native component.

Comment: have you found any solution that works

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to display your own UIViewController in the react-native app. So to implement this create a new NativeModule on the native ios side and access it on the react-native side. You can check how to do that [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios)

Then you can call a function on this module. Then to present your UIViewController you need to access rootViewController as shown in the code below:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;

[rootViewController presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So in this way, you can present your own UIViewController.